# How to copy entire row from worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA. I have this sub procedure CutePaste, that I call in worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range), that executes whenever the value in column "F" is changed. My goal is to copy the entire row of the cell changed and paste it into another sheet ("Cast Worked"). My code right now only copies the updated cell and paste that to the new sheet. Please advise how I can copy the entire row of the updated cell.

```
Sub CutPaste()

  If Not Intersect(myTarget, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveCell.Activate    
    a = Sheets("Cast Worked").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1    
    Sheets("Cast Worked").Range("A" & a).Value = ActiveCell.Value    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select    
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. You can use the [Range.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) method to do this. Furthermore you need to pass the target from the `worksheet_change` event to your subroutine.

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
  'Pass target range to subroutine
  CutPaste(Target)
End Sub

Sub CutPaste(myTarget As Range) 
  If Not Intersect(myTarget, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then        
    a = Sheets("Cast Worked").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1    
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cast Worked").Range("A" & a)
    Target.Offset(1, 0).Select    
  End If  
End Sub
```

I removed `ActiveCell.Activate` since setting the active cell to active is superfluous.

Comment: Thank you so much JNevill!!! This worked for copying the row, however, my code allows me to copy & paste the cell each time it is updated onto a new row of another sheet without overwriting the existing data. Please advise as how I can modify your code to follow what I originally had.

Comment: That's exactly what should happen with this code that is written. It finds the first empty row in `Cast Worked` sheet by looking at column A (starting at the last row and working up until it finds the first non-empty row) and then pastes into that row.

Comment: I just made a minor change though to do `Target.Offset(1, 0).Select` instead of `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` although that shouldn't affect what gets cut and where it gets copied.

Comment: Ok perfect! Thanks again!